# Open random website on button click visual basic

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

Hey I have been stuck on this bug.I hope someone can help, so in my .NET program when you press a button a timer starts which opens up multiple Internet Explorer windows but the problem is that I want each window opened to go to a random site from one of these options google, facebook ,twitter and yahoo. But I am not sure how to do that. PLEASE HELP!!!

this what i have so far

```
  Private Sub SPAM_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles SPAM.Click
        Timer1.Enabled = True
    End Sub

    Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
        IE()
    End Sub
    Sub IE()
        Dim oIE As Object

        oIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

        oIE.navigate2("www.google.com", "www.facebook.com", "www.twitte.com", "www.yahoo.com")
        oIE.Height = CInt(Int((1000 * Rnd()) + 1))
        oIE.Width = CInt(Int((1000 * Rnd()) + 1))
        oIE.Visible = True

    End Sub
```

Comment: -1 for tag spam, `PLEASE H3LP :0 fast` in general, and `H3LP` in particular.  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: no FAST service here

Comment: you want it *WHEN*????????????????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider that you are having a button `randomURL` its click event will open random websites in the browser, the following is the snippet for this:

```
Private Sub randomURL_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    Dim url() As String = {"www.google.com", "www.facebook.com", "www.twitte.com", "www.yahoo.com"}
    Dim randoNumber As Integer = CInt(Math.Ceiling(Rnd() * 3))
    Dim oIE As Object
    oIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    oIE.navigate2(url(randoNumber))
    oIE.Height = CInt(Int((1000 * Rnd()) + 1))
    oIE.Width = CInt(Int((1000 * Rnd()) + 1))
    oIE.Visible = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you want to do something random in VB.NET, you pretty much always need to start with the `Random` class.  Unfortunately, use of `Randomize` and `Rnd` is still taught and suggested by many but, in VB.NET, it's just bad code.

In your case, you should create a single instance of the `Random` class and then call its `Next` method multiple times.  Each call will generate a random `Integer` that you can then use as an index into your array of URLs.

By the way, you should probably just be calling `Process.Start` to open the URL, unless you specifically need to automate the IE instance afterwards.